# Why was my edit rejected for changing the original post too much?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I edited a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543388/transpose-column-value-to-row-in-t-sql) with minor layout changes and I changed a text back to what the original asker had typed. (The editor before me had made a rather large change to an original sentence that I found less comprehensible than the original text - this is of course always somewhat personal... The rejected edit is here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2469886)

The edit was then rejected because

> This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost. (2 times)

and

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post. (1 time)

So now I'm wondering: do the people that check the suggested edits only see the last edit and the newly suggested edit? And why was my edit rejected while it put back the original authors sentence, while the edit before mine was approved? Still learning here, so all suggestions and tips are welcome!

Comment: I think the problem is that your edit wasnt really necessary there, i mean,it did make the question clearer but not by a considerable margin. You only expanded what he had written. Maybe that is why the moderator or user thought it wasnt required.

Comment: @prince: could well be. I suppose my edit comment was not very clear either, now that I'm looking at it again - I specifically made that edit because I thought the text had changed too much compared to the original text, should have made that much more explicit.

Comment: Simulateously too minor and too large. Impressive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the reviewers don't see that you are actually rephrasing the OP's own words from a [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17543388/3).

You are spot on when you said that reviewers only see the latest revision and your suggested edit in the reviewing screen.

One way to avoid this kind of misunderstanding is to include as much relevant details in your edit comment as possible. For example you can include the link to OP's own revision,

> Rephrased the question based on OP's own words from revision #3 (https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17543388/3)

Also, keep in mind there is no hard and fast rules when it comes to what construes "too radical" and "too minor". In some cases, there is simply no correct answer.

---

**Note**: For what it's worth, I'd have approved your edit because I don't think going from

> note the Answers to those may varies.

to

> both the Name and Attribute values to rows. The Attribute values may vary but the Name is always fixed.

really alters the meaning of the original post (or the latest revision). I mean, it is a reasonable (and helpful) clarification given the context (even without knowing that the latter was based on OP's original words).

Also, I've applied your suggested edits to the question.

Comment: RE: *"I'd have approved your edit"*, why not edit it now?

Comment: Very helpful answer, thank you. I'll sure include much more details in my edit comment next time when the edit is not overly obvious an improvement, keeping in mind that the reviewers don't see all former edits at once.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Done and done.