# See edit diff before it has been accepted

Tags: support, suggested-edits, diff

Are you able to see the revision diff ([eg](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12234577/revisions)) for a question/answer you just edited?

I.e. It hasn't been accepted yet, so it mightn't appear in the actual revision history.
Is there a way to see the edit you just made in this handy view?

Because I know during [suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127497/suggested-edit-diff-shows-different-results-depending-upon-mode) reviews people watch out for [too many lines changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187973/why-was-my-edit-rejected-for-changing-the-original-post-too-much), and it'd be nice to keep track of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are you able to see the revision diff (eg) for a question/answer you just edited?

Yes. Go to the **Activity** tab in your profile, and find the suggested edit you just submitted - if you have a lot of activity, it may help if you filter to only **suggestions**.

Then click the **suggested edit link**:

[image: The edit link is named 'suggested edit']

This will take you to a diff of your edit, where you can also see rejections/approvals.